# Example for CLING Upnp

Tags: android, upnp, android-cling

I using Cling UpnpBrowser demo in below link.

http://4thline.org/projects/download/misc/

I'm using 2 phone to run it. But this app can not list device.

Can you give me a video demo or some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take some clues from the following links hope it will help you

[1] https://github.com/jinzora/jinzora-api-demo

[2] https://github.com/trishika/DroidUPnP

[3] https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.droidupnp

[4] http://blog.csdn.net/lancees/article/details/8477513